# Joining tables through a common table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

If I have

Table A, B, C

A and B have a relation
B and C have a different relation

I cannot  see a related column between A and C
but I would like to combine columns from A and C….

Is there a way to do that? Does This even logically make sense?

Comment: There is a good explanation at http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/13/sql-server-introduction-to-joins-basic-of-joins/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it does logically makes sense.

since A relates B and B relates C --> Then A relates C. that's known as `Transitive Relationship`.

you can join between A and C through B. that is Join A with B and then B with C

```
select A.*
from A
inner join B on A.somecolumn = B.somecolumn
inner join C on C.somecolumn = B.somecolumn
```

Where `somecolumn` is a common or related column between joined table(s)

Comment: Do you know how I can do this in SQL?

Answer (score 1):

Say, Tables A & B had common column AB and tables B & C had a common column BC, then you could use a query similar to the following (table B would have column AB and BC while A would have just AB and C would have just BC):

```
select A.*, C.*
from A
  join B ON A.AB = B.AB
  join C ON B.BC = C.BC
```